# logging errors in async functions

Tags: node.js, async-await

I have this code:

```
async function getURL() {
   try {
       await fetch("http://www.blah.com");
       return 0;
   } catch (err) {
       return err;
   }
}

getURL().then( result => {
    if (result === 0) console.log("success");
    else console.log(result);
});
```

The fetch will fail and the error is logged to the console.  How do I rework the code so it uses async and try/catch everywhere?  That is, I'm looking to avoid doing getURL().then for the sake of consistency.

EDIT:

For those downvoting me, `await getURL()` won't work as it's invalid syntax.

EDIT2:

Tried this but it didn't catch the error:

```
async function getURL() {
    return await fetch("http://www.blah.com");
}

let result = async function() {return await getURL();}

try {
    result();
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
}
```

Comment: Why dont you just use `await` if you dont want to use `then`?

Comment: `await getURL()` is invalid syntax. You can only use await inside an async function.

Comment: Could this be a solution? `let result = (async function() {return await getURL();})()`

Comment: I tried it as per the second edit to the post.  But now it doesn't catch the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realize now async functions always return a promise.  Even if you throw an error it still gets wrapped up into a promise.  Therefore using try/catch won't help.  This is how I ended up writing the code:

```
async function getURL() {
    return await fetch("http://fake");
 }

 getURL().then( () => console.log("success")).catch( (e) => console.log(e));
```

Answer (score 1):

Every time you need to catch an error from promise, either using `new Promise`, `async-await` or `generator` you need to use `.then()` or you can do something like this another `async-await`.

```
async function getURL() {
    try {
        await fetch("http://www.blah.com");
        return 0; // EDIT: just returning value which is success
    } catch (err) {
        return err; // EDIT: returning value not rejecting a promise
    }
}

async function main () {
    try {
        let result = await getURL();
        if (result === 0) console.log("success");
        console.log(result); // EDIT: error will be print.
    }
    catch (err) { // EDIT: getURL() never rejects so always success.
        console.log(err);
    }
});

main();
```

This situation doesn't really occurs as while our main function in `server-side` or `client-side` are async and handling this for us.

Like using `express`:

```
app.post('/api', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        let result = await getURL();
        res.send(async);
    }
    catch(err) {
        res.send(err);
    }
});
```

EDIT: `asyn-await` doesn't `reject` or `resolve` a call, just return a value. thus must be used carefully.

```
function fetch(url) {
    return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
        let x = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(9) + 1);
        // 50-50 resolve or reject
        if(x%2===0) return resolve(false); //resolve with `false` statement
        reject(true); // reject with `true` still a reject
    });
}

async function getURL() {
    try {
        await fetch("http://www.blah.com"); 
        return 0; // if fetch resolve
    } catch (err) { //only if fetch reject
        return err;
    }
}

async function main () {
    try {
        let result = getURL();
        if (result === 0) console.log("success"); //getURL never reject any call
        console.log(result);
    }
    catch (err) { // getURL doesnt reject
        console.log(err);
    }
};

main();
```

Comment: Thanks Navin.  I tried the code above (with getURL and main, not the express code).  It doesn't print an error message to the console.  The only way I can get it to print an error is if I do:  `getURL().then( result => console.log(result));` in the try block in main function.

Comment: I'm also curious why `getURL().catch( e => console.log(e))` doesn't log the error.  I have to use `.then`  I'm assuming when fetch fails it returns a promise in rejected state.

Comment: Thst's because we are returning an `error` object. How can our `main` function know it's an `error`, like in tradition promise we can use `resolve()` and `reject()` what we pass in these function doesn't really matter. `getURL` never rejected anything just returned an object.

Comment: Thanks Navin, I understand it now.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your whole code inside an instantly executed async function like this:

```js
// service.js
async function getURL() {
  return await fetch("http://www.blah.com");
}

// your.module.js
(async function() {
  // do things...

  try {
    let result = await getURL();
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }

  // do things...

  res.send({});
});
```

Comment: I tried the IIFE but I'm afraid it is still not catching the error.  I'm confused.

Comment: I realize now why this can't work.  async always returns a promise, so it makes no sense to surround `result()` in try/catch block.  Only choice is to use `.catch`